# Kendo UI Grid Column typed date has a trouble

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which would have many columns typed date. These all grids is generated from a generic function, so that I cannot know whether the column type is date or not. There is one rule validates through all columns. It is that all columns `name` end with "Date" suffix. For instance, createDate, editDate, visitedDate, etc...

So that, I can understand that it can be date and I parse it like you can see at the dataSource `parse` function
I have trouble when I update the cell. It does not reflect its own value to Model. The date column ***proto*** function returns "Invalid Date" error. I do not understand what it happen

```
var dataSource =  new kendo.data.DataSource({
    "data": [
        {
            "hidden_gridColumns": "",
            "id": "21632",
            "projectId": "146",
            "customerTypeId": "4",
            "district": "0",
            "fieldSize": "12",
            "fieldType": "0",
            "floorCoveringType": "12",
            "lastChangeDate": null,
            "estimatedModificationDate": null,
            "latestCompany": ""
        }
    ],
    "schema": {
        "model": {
            "id": "id",
            "fields": {
                "gridColumns": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "projectId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "customerTypeId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "district": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "fieldSize": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "fieldType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "floorCoveringType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastChangeDate": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "estimatedModificationDate": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "latestCompany": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        parse: function(data){
            $.each(data,
            function(rowNo,
            row){
                $.each(row,
                function(colName,
                column){
                    if(colName.indexOf("Date")>=0){
                        console.log(colName + " taranıyor");
                        row[colName] = kendo.parseDate(row[colName], "dd-MM-yyyy");
                    }
                });
            });
            return data;
        }
    },
    "batch": true
})
```

And this is my columns structure:

```
var columns = [
    {
        "title": "gridColumns",
        "field": "gridColumns",
        "hidden": true
    },
    {
        "title": "id",
        "field": "id",
        "hidden": true
    },
    {
        "title": "projectId",
        "field": "projectId",
        "hidden": true
    },
    {
        "title": "Müşteri Tipi",
        "field": "customerTypeId",
        "hidden": false,
        "width": "91",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "1",
                "text": "Yurtiçi "
            },
            {
                "value": "2",
                "text": "Yurtdışı"
            },
            {
                "value": "3",
                "text": "Spor Kulübü"
            },
            {
                "value": "4",
                "text": "Diğer"
            },
            {
                "value": "5",
                "text": "Üniversite"
            },
            {
                "value": "6",
                "text": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "district",
        "field": "district",
        "hidden": true,
        "width": "132"
    },
    {
        "title": "Saha Ölçüsü",
        "field": "fieldSize",
        "hidden": false,
        "width": "85"
    },
    {
        "title": "Saha Türü",
        "field": "fieldType",
        "hidden": false,
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "1",
                "text": "Açık"
            },
            {
                "value": "0",
                "text": "Kapalı"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Halı Cinsi",
        "field": "floorCoveringType",
        "hidden": false,
        "width": "76"
    },
    {
        "title": "Son Halı değişim Tarih",
        "field": "lastChangeDate",
        "hidden": false,
        "format": "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"
    },
    {
        "title": "Tahmini Yenileme Tarihih",
        "field": "estimatedModificationDate",
        "hidden": false

    },
    {
        "title": "Son Çalıştığı Halı Firması",
        "field": "latestCompany",
        "hidden": false
    }
]
```

Comment: I think the issue is related to the datatype. Please check the date which you are updating is  a valid JavaScript date object or not. I think doesn't remain a date object.

Comment: I enter the value through a Kendo date picker element. Already, ıt shows a datepicker if you have selected the field type as "date". You can look at my dataSource definetion.

Comment: ok can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot put them into the fiddle. Already here is the whole case. if we can establish a special contact, I will let you to examine my codes.. What about you? My address is, albeniz@mail.com

Comment: For which date does it return an invalid date? I see some records that have `null` as date, what should be the date for those `null`?

Comment: Yes, the value is null however, Although I enter a value editing cell, it cannot take this value..

Comment: Also, please look at  the parse() method..

Comment: All these settings that I asked for the lastChangeDate column.

Comment: Just out of interest what happens if you take the date formatting off the columns. Does it work? If so it may be a localization issue eg the columns are expecting en-US date format (the default) so MM-DD-YYYY rather than the usual en-GB (DD-MM-YYYY) format.

Comment: @DavidShorthose this is not localization issue. I faced a  parsing problem, I overcome it through the parse() function.

Comment: You can check it, https://gist.github.com/e5545b1f3ec7572fe690.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by the code below:

```
     parse: function(response) {
                 var tmpData=[];
                 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var tmpRow = response[i];
                        $.each(tmpRow, function(colNo, colValue){
                           if(colNo.indexOf("Date")>-1){                                 
                               tmpRow[colNo]=kendo.parseDate(new Date(tmpRow[colNo]));                               
                           } 
                        });
                        tmpData.push(tmpRow);
                      }
                return tmpData;
}
```